# Nested elements inside object with similar tag/class

Tags: jquery, html, filter, find

I have a div with some text. I need to get an array of all the elements of similar tag inside this div.
I'm storing selected string data in a variable and convert it to object.
I need to get all the element with "sen" tag in this string.
I tried using 'find' and 'filter' but both of them give me incomplete results.
My require array here will be, all the 'sen' tags i.e. from class '.h351' till class '.h356'.

Here is a fiddle [test link](https://jsfiddle.net/trupti11/kxt4x55m/1/) to get the clear idea. Check the console to see the result.

JS code

```
var htmlSet = '<span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="reset black2"><sen name="351" class="h h351">Sagen</sen></span><sen xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="352" class="h h352"> Sie bitte nicht, der Schüler verfüge nicht über die nötigen kognitiven Funktionen, um sich das derart verteilte Wissen überhaupt anzueignen.</sen><sen xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="353" class="h h353"> Denn ebendiese Funktionen sind es, die sich mit dem Träger und durch den Träger ändern.</sen><sen xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="354" class="h h354"> Durch die Schrift und den Buchdruck etwa hatte das Gedächtnis sich so sehr gewandelt, daß Montaigne sagen konnte, er ziehe einen wohlbeschaffenen einem wohlgefüllten Kopf vor.</sen><sen xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="355" class="h h355"> Dieser Kopf ist unterdessen noch einmal mutiert.</sen><sen xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="356" class="h h356"></sen>';
var htmlSetArr = $(htmlSet).find('sen');
console.log("array using find");
console.log(htmlSetArr);
var htmlSetArr1 = $(htmlSet).filter('sen');
console.log("array using filter");
console.log(htmlSetArr1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to sort it by this way.
Wrapped the content inside another div and 'find' worked fine.

Here is the update fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/trupti11/kxt4x55m/6/).

JS Code

```
var htmlSet = '<span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="reset black2"><sen name="351" class="h h351">Sagen</sen></span><sen xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="352" class="h h352"> Sie bitte nicht, der Schüler verfüge nicht über die nötigen kognitiven Funktionen, um sich das derart verteilte Wissen überhaupt anzueignen.</sen><sen xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="353" class="h h353"> Denn ebendiese Funktionen sind es, die sich mit dem Träger und durch den Träger ändern.</sen><sen xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="354" class="h h354"> Durch die Schrift und den Buchdruck etwa hatte das Gedächtnis sich so sehr gewandelt, daß Montaigne sagen konnte, er ziehe einen wohlbeschaffenen einem wohlgefüllten Kopf vor.</sen><sen xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="355" class="h h355"> Dieser Kopf ist unterdessen noch einmal mutiert.</sen><sen xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="356" class="h h356"></sen>';
htmlSet = '<div>'+htmlSet+'</div>';
var htmlSetArr = $(htmlSet).find('sen');
console.log("array using find");
console.log(htmlSetArr);
console.log($(htmlSet).find('.h'))
var htmlSetArr1 = $(htmlSet).filter('sen');
console.log("array using filter");
console.log(htmlSetArr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$('.h').each(function(e){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

or using the sen tag:

```
// Using the sen tag...
$('sen').each(function(e){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kxt4x55m/5/

Comment: The data is stored in variable, it is not on the page. In that case I anyways need to use 'find' and it is not working properly.